# How to activate a button when a condition is met?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have a button that should be activated after the user selects a photo from library or take a photo. But as long as there is no photo the button should not work.

Comment: Are you working with UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: I’m working with UIKit

Answer (score 0):

UIButton has a property called `isEnabled` (refer to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618217-isenabled)).

To enable the button you can write:

```
myButton.isEnabled = true
```

**More detailed explanation:**
First of all you need to disable the button, when the ViewController is loaded. Ideally you do this in the `viewWillAppear` function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  myButton.isEnabled = false
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

And when the photo is loaded you can enable the button:

```
func selectPhoto() {
  // your code to select the photo
  myButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Oh, ya. I already did this, but it works from the very beginning, and I need the button to turn on after the photo appears on the screen.

Comment: I added a few more details to my answer. If that doesn't help you, I need some more details on where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Before the user selects a photo from library or take a photo

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

After the user selects a photo from library or take a photo

```
button.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: yes, I know this, but I just need a condition in the form of a code.